# Moq, Visual Studio Unit Testing - Tests keep skipping a method in a mocked service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, moq, castle-windsor

I'm testing a GET action method that calls a public method in a service that has been mocked.

The test fails. When I placed a break-point in the service method, I found that it gets skipped during execution of the test. How do I ensure that the service method doesn't get skipped?

I'm using Visual Studio Unit Testing Tools, Moq, Castle Windsor

Comment: Can you include relevant code? The class/methods under test, as well as the actual tests

Comment: Sorry, can't share code
I'm just trying to understand if it is common for methods of mocked services to get skipped while running tests, and if they are, how to make them not skipped?

Comment: Sorry, we can't provide help then. Please share a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: BTW If you **mock** a class then you will have something that will behave like the class but it is not the class itself and a method call on the mock will not execute the class method. That is the nature of a mock.

Comment: Ah thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As @sir-rufo stated in the comments, it is not sufficient to just mock the class, you have to define the behaviour of the methods within that class. For instance:

```cs
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething("ping")).Returns(true);
```

You can find more examples on [Moq github](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Follow up question, if the service method calls a private method, will the behavior of that method need to be defined as well?

Comment: No, since you are mocking the function it won't actually execute. It will just return X given Y as you define.

Comment: @JamesBurani It seems you did not get the point of a mock. The mock has nothing, really nothing to do with the implementation of the mocked class. The mock will behave to others **as if** it were an instance of the mocked class with all the **public** properties and methods but without any implementation.